# Can process calls synchronised methods of class instead of thread in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, java-threads

If there is some class A which has synchronised methods,then if some thread(s) ,T1 and T2, calls the synchronised methods of class A, then it is fine. But if instead of T1 and T2, I use normal classes that dont extend thread or implement runnable interface ,say P1 and P2, then if P1 and P2 calls methods of class A, will it be a normal thread safe operation or can there be any problem?

Comment: As far as I know, there is always a `Thread` executing any code in Java. Anywhere in your code you can get the current `Thread` instance by invoking `Thread t = Thread.currentThread();` (which is a static method). So a `Thread` would actually call your P1 (or P2) class method, which would call the synchronized methods of A. Even `main` method is run by a `Thread` (the *main thread*). Can you provide some code representing your question?

Answer (score 0):

Calls to the methods of class A from your processes/classes P1 and P2 will belong to the individual objects of class A created in those classes (P1/P2).

P1:function1() -> 
A a1 = new A();
a1.method1();
a1.method2();
P2:function2() -> 
A a2 = new A();
a2.method1();
a2.method2();
DriverClass:main() -> 
P1 p1 = new P1(); 
p1.function1();
P2 p2 = ne P2();
p2.function2();
Individual calls inside of above classes will be sync calls and since there is no multi-threading involved, so these calls will be thread safe. Applicable even if method1() and method2() were *static* as well.
 However, if you have static method in class A and plan to deploy P1 and P2 as some sort of service trying to access class A's(also a service) static method (non-syncronized) in some independent manner, that's similar to how you would have accessed that same static method using different threads. In this case, dirty reads might happen and you need to consider thread safety in this mechanism.
Hope it clears your doubt otherwise you may post a sample scenario code for better understanding.

Comment: I mean, if we create A a = new A() and then pass this same a to both p1 and p2. Now if A has method which are synchronized, then when p1 and p2 tries to access A's a1 and a2 methods(which are synchronised), then will it be safe operation?P1 and P2 can be considered as two threads ?even if they dont extend thread and implement runnable?

Comment: I think I understood your problem. Short and crisp answer to this can be - In any system, where multiple processes (P1 and P2 in this case) try to access the same resource (A), there are always chances of resource contentions and race conditions. In order to avoid that, different techniques are used (like semaphores, locks, etc.) In your case, 'synchronized' will internally take care of it (as far as your resource remains the same i.e. Object 'a' of class 'A') and you can safely perform your tasks.